# Can we use some character other than forward slash (/) for moving between directories in linux?

Tags: linux

In Linux, can we use some other character other than forward slash `/`.

I don't want to use `/` for moving between folders. I am just doing some experiment in scripting, so was just curious to know.

e.g. Instead of `cd ../../` I may use `cd ..-..-` or any other character which a file name can have.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? What are you trying to accomplish and what is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: For what do you need it for? :S

Comment: It is a simple question, why not just answer it instead of asking questions back?

Comment: Because **the question has no real sense**. The `/` is **defined as separator** between directories **within the kernel**, and (except by changing the kernel yourself incompatibly) there is no way to change that. I cannot imagine a valid reason to change it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/` is not an artefact of the operating system, it is a notation agreed upon by the interpreters, I'd say. Therefore you have two alternatives to replace it:

- rebuild your command interpreter (e.g. bash), maybe you also have to rebuid the file system system calls, not sure about that, actually.
- create wrappers around file system commands like `cd` for example by usin alias definitions. Those can replace the 'alternate hierarchy character' you suggest.

But be aware of the fact that you have to escape that character if it is contained in an ordinary file or folder name.

Oh, and one more kind of half an alternative:

- you could also create a font that shows some different pictogram for the character `/`. That way you still *use* that character, but it looks totally different.

Ah, and...

- you could execute a `powershell` in `wine`, then you can use MS-Windows style back slashes ( `\` ) instead of the normal forward slashes.

Comment: Hmmm..3rd option looks a little easier, though not sure how I will do it. Thanks for the answers btw.

Comment: Are you sure this is handled by the interpreter? What happens if I do `fopen('/home/user/stuff')` in C? That doesn't go through the shell, does it?

Comment: No, the slash separator in paths is interpreted by the Linux kernel. A directory entry cannot have slash or null characters (all other are permitted by the kernel). The kernel knows about `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: The same applies to C or whatever compiled language. In the end those languages also interpret the code, just in a different way: by preparing some form of optimized code that can be executed directly without an additional runtime interpreter. But the algorithm used is the same: the path is split and the herarchy levels are traeated one by one. The question is how you call that library that implements the algorith. Is it part of the language or of the system? I am currently not sure of the location is inside the kernel or inside libc, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid not as I know. You may write some alias like below to avoid tedious type.

```
cd..='cd ..'
cd...='cd ../..'
cd....='cd ../../..'
cd.....='cd ../../../..'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Posix definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266)  pathname consists of optional beginning slash followed by zero or more filenames separated by slashes. As others have stated, it's possible to write a script to escape slashes and convert other characters to slashes, but linux doesn't offer a way to do this by default.